# MySQL 5.5.2 community version performance and hang issue

Tags: mysql

We have a 64GB RAM server with HP-UX OS and installed MySQL version 5.5.2.
We observe frequent issues with the database and we must restart the database every 2 or 3 days which is impacting the stability of our application.
Let me know which details are required to solve this issue.

Comment: "We observe frequent issues": What issues do you observe?

Comment: *"we must restart the database every 2 or 3 days"* Why? What happens if you don't restart? Restarting a DBMS is not a solution.

Comment: What changes did you make to the configuration (my.cnf)?  What other large programs run on the same server?  What is in the log?

Comment: What issues do you observe? - We observe database stop responding frequently and we need to restart database

Comment: What issues do you observe? - Database stop responding and our application not able to respond due to database hence we must need to restart database

Comment: What changes did you make to the configuration (my.cnf)? What other large programs run on the same server? What is in the log?
* No any other programs running on this server, this standalone server for only database running on it. Please find below my.cnf configured :

Comment: * No any other programs running on this server, this standalone server for only database running on it. Please find below my.cnf configured :
default-storage-engine=INNODB
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=10M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_log_buffer_size=32M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=22G
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=1000
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:500M:autoextend
max_connections=3200
max_connect_errors=1000
tmp_table_size=128M
max_heap_table_size=128M